# ng-repeat with fadetoggle jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have many form in my angular app like this

```
<form ng-submit="" ng-repeat="app in apps">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="single-app" >
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="check-app">{{app.name}}</label>
            </div>
            <img src="{{app.url}}" height="140" width="140">
            <div id="description">
            <textarea></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

I want all text area hidden default and specific show text area when i checked box

I tried this jquery code but doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#description").hide();
$('#check-app').click(function(){
    $('#description').fadeToggle();
})
});
```

Comment: if you wanna play with angular, use angular methods. Use `ng-model` of checbox to activate `ng-show` of textarea...and can use `ng-class` to create the animation using `ng-animate` methods

Comment: must read:  [How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Answer (score 1):

**It is not the angular way to solve it, still to make your script to work**

ID of an element **must be unique**, use class to group similar elemets

```
<form ng-submit="" ng-repeat="app in apps">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="single-app" >
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="check-app"/>{{app.name}}</label>
            </div>
            <img src="{{app.url}}" height="140" width="140"/>
            <div class="description">
                <textarea></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".description").hide();
    $(document).on('click', '.check-app', function () {
        $(this).closest('.single-app').find('.description').stop(true, true).fadeToggle();
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JnKzv/)

One easy solution using ng-way(without slide animation)

```
<form ng-submit="" ng-repeat="app in apps">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="single-app" >
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="check-app" ng-model="visible"/>{{app.name}}</label>
            </div>
            <img src="{{app.url}}" height="140" width="140"/>
            <div class="description" ng-show="visible">
                <textarea></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JnKzv/)

Comment: have to delegate due to the `ng-repeat` but is really senseless using jQuery for this. And hide() won't work due to angular digest cycles

Comment: best approach when using jQuery for DOM manipulation is use it from within angular directive....then elements exist when it fires and angular has already done it's thing

Comment: @charlietfl I was planning to write one... then got into something else

Comment: last comment not really meant for you....I know you're on top of your game! ...meant more for OP.